# Cursor limit in mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

Iam using mongo as an db for my web app. Java code queries the data from mongo. Curntly there is >40000 in mongo . In one of my api it will return all that documents. So i need only 50 documents to show on the web page. I have tried `cursor.limit(50)` but it only reduces the time taken by while loop. so i think the whole time is taking from this code `DBCursor cursor=collection.find(query,field)` . Any ways to reduce it..?.

Comment: indexing and data restitution are two different aspects .. you need to index before being able to restitute .. as desired .. whatever the system you're using you need to know "what" before "how" ^^ , and as indexing is gready  results should be similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Database Profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler) section of the mongodb documentation. It describes ways of finding out how much time the query execution is taking and then in a later section talks about how to optimize the query.